# Apache/mod_wsgi/django/arch linux woes since 64 bit upgrade, despite being able to import all libraries

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, archlinux

I've been trying to figure out what's causing this issue for hours but with no luck.

Since migrating my arch linux installation to 64 bit I've found my django sites don't work, with error 500. I'm using python2, which is 64 bit:

```
>>> import struct
>>> print struct.calcsize("P") * 8
64
```

And I also have 64 bit mod_wsgi2: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/mod_wsgi2/

Here's an example log:

```
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.312829 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898] mod_wsgi (pid=19537): Target WSGI script '/home/james/sites/dse/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.312872 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898] mod_wsgi (pid=19537): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/james/sites/dse/django.wsgi'.
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.312916 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.312953 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898]   File "/home/james/sites/dse/django.wsgi", line 12, in <module>
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.312997 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.313006 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.313056 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.313066 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.313078 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898]     import datetime
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.313103 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898] ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
[Mon Feb 20 21:42:40.313185 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 19537] [client 146.179.195.99:62898] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/httpd/error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
```

So, I tried to import all these things manually to see if I got an error, nope:

```
[james@tryptophan ~]$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 21 2016, 07:16:46)
[GCC 6.2.1 20160830] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> import django
>>> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>>> from django.utils.version import get_version
```

I've checked that I've got:
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

In my httpd.conf, and the contents of the /home/james/sites/dse/django.wsgi file implicated in the error haven't changed in about 3 years (!) and are as follows:

```
[james@tryptophan dse]$ cat django.wsgi
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/james/sites/dse/django_dse')
sys.path.append('/home/james/sites/dse')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_dse.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

So I'm not sure what to do. I mean it sounds like a 32/64 bit compatibility issue with the error being ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 - but I cannot figure out what's causing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using a Python virtual environment, did you recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the error was actually in a separate apache module being loaded that was NOT 64 bit. I was loading a 32 bit module in my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
```

The way I actually identified this was by running the 'apachectl' program which then gave me an error related to the import of the 32 bit module.

When this was commented out, all of my 64 bit django websites came back to life. Quite why this manifested in the way it did, I do not know...